# Handling PreviewMouseDown and PreviewMouseUp events in Prism

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have a Prism application and I'm attempting to bind PreviewMouseDown and PreviewMouseUp button events in my view to commands in my view model.  When I run the code I see the following exception:

[image]

As a workaround, I'm currently binding to methods in the view and use a reference to the data context of the view model to execute the command. This works but doesn't seem correct because the view now has knowledge of the view model.

What is the proper way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind events to commands like, for example, the `Command` property of a button.

Luckily, you don't need to, because you have the `Command` property. It even disables the button if the command returns `false` from `CanExecute`.

If you have something other than a button or something other than `MouseDown`, you can use `InvokeCommandAction` (from Prism or from Interactivity)...

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        <!-- or -->
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your answer, that would allow me to see mouse events within the window but still does not allow me to see the up/down events of the button.   What I'm trying to do is start a motor moving when the user is holding a button down and stop the motor from moving when the user releases the button.

Comment: You can handle `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` this way on a button, too, of course, but then it doesn't need to be a button... a `TextBlock` would do, too